# What is the difference between these two layer thumbnail types?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

What is the difference between the two layer thumbnail types pictured:

[image]

Vs.

[image]

How do I bring about the second, if the first is currently appearing whenever I create a new Shape Layer, for example?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layer thumbnail type can be changed from the Panel Options window.

[image]

Your top example is “None”. It looks like you want the smallest thumbnail size under it.